# Which force serves as the centripetal force for a particle on the surface of a water wave?

Tags: forces, waves, centripetal-force

I read [this article](https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/waves/wavemotion.html) about the motion of a particle on the water surface in a water wave.

See the picture :

[image]

The water molecules move on a circular path. But I don't know why do they do so.

**So I want to know which force plays the role of  centripetal force for this motion ?**

Comment: I think the main reason is that the water wave is not a purely transverse wave. When producing a wave in water, the surface of water obviously experience a longitudinal wave effect. Because of this and together with the shear viscosity of water, the bottom layers of water will experience longitudinal wave as well, but less. Intuitively, the combination of both the transverse and longitudinal waves will cause circular or elliptical motion of water molecules.

Comment: I think you may find your answer in this link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438827/why-are-water-waves-transverse-or-up-and-down/438850     Also, FMI, see this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164491/why-cant-transverse-waves-travel-through-a-liquid

Comment: I think the answer below (by @mathstackuser12) is complete.

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon Andrew's answer (as per the comments):

Consider a mass of fluid of volume V enclosed by a surface S which is fixed in space.  Let $\rho $ be the density of the fluid at position $\mathbf{r}=\left( x,y,z \right)$ and time t, then the mass enclosed by the surface is simply $\int\limits_{{}}^{{}}{\rho dV}$ .  Let $\mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)$ be the velocity field of the fluids motion, then the rate at which mass flows outwards across the surface S (with outward normal n) is
$$\int\limits_{S}^{{}}{\left( \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n} \right)\rho dS}=\int\limits_{V}^{{}}{\nabla \cdot \left( \rho \mathbf{v} \right)dV}$$
by Guass’ divergence theorem. The change in mass of fluid in the volume over time must be related to the rate of loss (because positive is outward facing) and so
$$-\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int\limits_{V}^{{}}{\rho dV}=\int\limits_{V}^{{}}{\nabla \cdot \left( \rho \mathbf{v} \right)dV}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}+\nabla \cdot \left( \rho \mathbf{v} \right)=0$$
Or
$$\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla \rho +\rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}=0\Rightarrow \frac{D\rho }{Dt}+\left( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} \right)\rho =0$$
which is the standard mass conservation/continuity equation using the material derivative D.  If the fluid is incompressible then we have $\rho =\text{constant}$ and the equation of continuity becomes simply
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}=0$$
Assume that the only forces acting on an elemental volume of liquid, by the remaining liquid, are normal pressure forces acting on the surrounding surface.  Letting F represent external forces per unit mass, then by Newton’s second law we have
$$\rho \frac{D\mathbf{v}}{Dt}=-\nabla p+\rho \mathbf{F}$$
That is for an incompressible and inviscid fluid, under the influence of gravity we have
$$\rho \left( \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)\cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right) \right)=-\nabla p\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)-\rho g\left( 0,0,1 \right)$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)=0$$
This represents four equations and four unknowns, i.e. velocity and pressure ${{v}_{j=1,2,3}},p$for an incompressible and inviscid fluid.  For water waves generally we’re interested in irrotational flow and so we can introduce a potential function $\mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)=\nabla \varphi \left( \mathbf{r},t \right)$
Using Green’s identity ${{\nabla }^{2}}\left( \mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b} \right)=\mathbf{a}\cdot {{\nabla }^{2}}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{b}\cdot {{\nabla }^{2}}\mathbf{a}+2\nabla \cdot \left( \left( \mathbf{b}\cdot \nabla  \right)\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}\times \nabla \times \mathbf{a} \right)$ with a zero-curl field we have $\tfrac{1}{2}{{\nabla }^{2}}\left( \mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{u} \right)=\nabla \cdot \left( \mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla  \right)\mathbf{u}\Rightarrow \tfrac{1}{2}\nabla \left( \mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{u} \right)=\left( \mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla  \right)\mathbf{u}$ and so

$$\rho \left( \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)}{\partial t}+\tfrac{1}{2}\nabla \left( \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v} \right) \right)=-\nabla \left( p\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)+\rho gz \right)$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)=0$$
Substituting for $\mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)=\nabla \varphi \left( \mathbf{r},t \right)$we find
$$\rho \nabla \left( \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial t}+\tfrac{1}{2}{{\left( \nabla \varphi  \right)}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\rho }p\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)+gz \right)=0$$
Integrating, where ${{p}_{0}}$ is the pressure at equilibrium when there is no wave present, we have Bernoulli’s equation, coupled with Laplace’s equation
$$p\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)={{p}_{0}}-\rho \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial t}-\rho \frac{1}{2}{{\left( \nabla \varphi  \right)}^{2}}-\rho gz$$
$${{\nabla }^{2}}\varphi =0$$
Let the fluid have a boundary surface S which acts as an interface separating it from other media (either a gas or another fluid etc).  Specifically, lets consider water interfacing with air.  We can represent the surface as an equation
$$S\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)=\eta \left( x,y,t \right)-z=0$$
The kinematic condition on the bounding surface is that the velocity of the surface should equal the velocity of the fluid, normal to its surface.   We have then at the surface
$$\frac{\partial \eta }{\partial t}={{v}_{z}}$$
Using the potential function this becomes
$$\frac{\partial \eta }{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}=0,\,\,\,\,z=\eta \left( x,y,t \right)$$
Bernoulli’s equation evaluated at the surface determines the pressure at all points on the surface, which must be ${{p}_{0}}$hence
$${{p}_{0}}={{p}_{0}}-\rho \frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial t}-\rho \frac{1}{2}{{\left( \nabla \varphi  \right)}^{2}}-\rho gz,\,\,\,\,z=\eta \left( x,y,t \right)$$
Now consider that the${{\left( \nabla \varphi  \right)}^{2}}$term comes from re-writing $\mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)\cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)$ .  For waves with period T and amplitude A and wave length L, the velocity of fluid in the wave will be approximately of the order A/T and so
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t}\simeq \frac{A}{{{T}^{2}}}$$
Similarly we could argue that $\mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)\cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)\simeq \frac{1}{L}{{\left( \frac{A}{T} \right)}^{2}}$.  Considering their ratio we have then
$$\frac{\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}}{\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t}}\simeq \frac{A}{L}\Rightarrow \mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}<<\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t}$$
if A<<L.  And therefore for waves of small amplitude we have approximately
$$\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial t}+gz=0,\,\,\,z=\eta \left( x,y,t \right)\simeq 0$$
In summary we have for a fluid filling the half space $z\le 0$
$$\frac{\partial \eta }{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z},\,\,z=0$$
$$\tag*{(kinematic boundary conditions)}$$
$$\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial t}+g\eta =0,\,\,z=0,\,\,t>0$$
$$\tag*{(dynamic boundary condition)}$$
$${{\nabla }^{2}}\varphi =0$$
$$\tag*{(irrotational/incompressible flow)}$$
$$\varphi \left( x,y,-\infty ,t \right)=0$$
$$\tag*{(boundary conditions)}$$

Let’s consider one-dimensional surface waves, meaning a surface profile given by $\,z=\eta \left( x,t \right)$ .  Note that
$$\varphi \left( x,z,t \right)=A{{e}^{kz}}\cos \left( kx-\omega t+\alpha  \right)$$
Satisfies Laplace’s equation and the boundary condition at $z=-\infty $.  Differentiating the dynamic boundary condition w.r.t to t and substituting for the kinematic boundary condition yields
$$\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}\varphi }{\partial {{t}^{2}}}+g\frac{\partial \varphi }{\partial z}=0,\,\,z=0$$
Substituting our solution for $\varphi $into this requirement, places conditions on $\omega $ and k, namely the dispersion relation $\omega =\sqrt{gk}$.  Effectively we have then for 1D waves with a free-boundary, the velocity in the fluid taking the form
$$v\left( \mathbf{r},t \right)=Ak{{e}^{kz}}\left( -\sin \left( kx-\omega t+\alpha  \right),0,\cos \left( kx-\omega t+\alpha  \right) \right)$$
Hence particles near the surface of the fluid have a velocity vector that rotates in a circle. Note the radius of these circles changes with the depth of water (they get smaller).  Therefore this predicts that at any fixed point within the fluid, the speed remains constant while the direction of fluid motion rotates. Then we get all the nice effects from the dispersion relation too (boat wakes etc)!

Answer (score 0):

Gravity pulls down, air pressure is perpendicular to the surface and internal forces keep the density of the water constant.

Comment: can u please elaborate somewhat more ?